# How to fix WPF render exception on floating panel resize?

Tags: wpf, citrix, xenapp

EDIT: This happens because the dockable panel is semi-transparent when it's moved to floating. The fix was to disable transparency.

I use a custom panel-feature (3rd party, non-public NuGet) that has visual-studio like dockable panels. If I float a panel and resize it (couple of times) on Citrix XenApp it crashes. With following stack in log file (only few lines).

```
Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88980406): UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406)

   at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()

   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender()

   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()

   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)

   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)

   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)

   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
```

It does not happen when I run it in any environment except Citrix. And it can be reproduced in all customer environments with same Citrix version. This was not reproducable with older version of Citrix XenApp but it's not possible to ask customers to downgrade.

This happens with Citrix version 7.6 on 2012 R2. Seems to happen on all 7.6 and one 7.9 installations.

Does not happen on 6.5 on 2008 R2.

Comment: You can find some hints [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/11/18/wpf-render-thread-failures/). Anyway you should provide some more detail about your code for reproducing your bug.

Comment: thanks. I've read that. i know there's almost no info in my question, but what can I provide? I can't send u nuget package of the SDK i'm using. Even less the source code. As this is reproducable only on some/one Citrix version(s), the hope for reproducing another program elsewhere are slim.

Comment: I see your point of view, but without details is almost impossibile to help you. For example which version of Citrix are you talking about? Which SDK? And so on...

Comment: @IlVic. I finally got the versions. I don't have access to the servers to see the installations ATM. SDK is not a public one and I don't have source code, only NuGet package from private server.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, along with the fix (disabling transparency).  I also just encountered the same problem in our Citrix environment (7.19 on Windows Server 2012 R2). Hopefully I will have a way to find the transparency, let alone disable it.  We use a third party dock manager too (Infragistics).